# how do I check whether user date and Time are set correctly in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to know how I can check if a users phone `date` and `time` are properly set.

Comment: `DateTime.now` gives you the current user time and you can contact a time server and ask for the time there and then compare (if you have network connection)

Comment: Following Gunter’s suggestion, once you have both time stamps, you can store the difference as timefix say. Then we you want an accuracy time stamp you can use DateTime.now+timefix.

Comment: saw this package on pub, thanks all,
[ntp package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ntp?fbclid=IwAR1vNfcVQLucCc6UhKlFO1ZPtrm2wYRJDreiQ2ERdrG1Wa2LGApcyZw-FiE#-readme-tab-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [NTP](https://pub.dev/packages/ntp) package to the network time protocol form http://pool.ntp.org

With this package, you can calculate the offset between the user time and network time

Example from documentation

```
import 'package:ntp/ntp.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  DateTime _myTime;
  DateTime _ntpTime;

  /// Or you could get NTP current (It will call DateTime.now() and add NTP offset to it)
  _myTime = await NTP.now();

  /// Or get NTP offset (in milliseconds) and add it yourself
  final int offset = await NTP.getNtpOffset(localTime: DateTime.now());
  _ntpTime = _myTime.add(Duration(milliseconds: offset));

  print('My time: $_myTime');
  print('NTP time: $_ntpTime');
  print('Difference: ${_myTime.difference(_ntpTime).inMilliseconds}ms');
}
```